# how to actually book the agenda of a meeting room?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-calendar

Is there any way in the office Graph API to really block the agenda of a resource?
I create meeting, using the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I add the room as a resource:

```
{
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "meetingroom@mytenant.com,
        "name": "The room"
      },
      "type": "resource"
    }
```

The event correctly appears in the calendar of the room, but I can also create an overlapping event, without any error message. How can I make sure that nobody can book the same room?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t checked the following, but you can verify by using outlook to schedule a meeting and including the room. Is it working when you try the same in Outlook?

If that also doesn’t work, I think your mailbox is not configured correctly.

Check out this page for common issues with Room mailboxes. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/resources-in-exchange-don-t-respond-to-meeting-requests-e6d24af5-36ae-5d87-b615-f292f3953dac

Comment: Hm, looks like that the graph call aways returns an OK, and only later is the accept/decline meeting sent by the room. This is either by design or an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look at [microsoft exchange documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-calendarprocessing?view=exchange-ps),
what you are looking for is `AutomateProcessing`

```
AutoAccept: Both the Calendar Attendant 
and resource booking attendant are enabled on the mailbox. 
This means that the Calendar Attendant updates the calendar, 
and then the resource booking assistant accepts the meeting based upon the policies. 
Eligible meeting organizers receive the decision directly without human intervention 
(free = accept; busy = decline).
```

ensure you add attendees to your create event call, like you already did. But also add location `(locationUri, uniqueId, locationType, uniqueIdType, displayName)` to be able to edit your booking through outlook app / webapp without loosing the room.